# How to get all stories and sub tasks from a specific user along with how much time spent on each item in JIRA

Tags: jql

I am trying to get all stories and sub-tasks for a specific user along with how much time spent on each item from starting of this year.

I am using JIRA version v8.5.9, where I have tried running the following query but it is not giving me the expected result, any help is appreciated.

`(issuetype = "Sub task") AND time spent > 0 and assignee = test123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following JQL query.

`(issuetype = "Sub task"  OR issuetype = Story )AND timespent > 0 AND assignee = test123 AND createdDate >= startOfYear()`

***Explanation:***

- Look for `Sub task` OR `story` first.
- Then make sure its `timespent`(looks like OP has a typo in OP's efforts) is more than 0 here.
- Then checking assignee should be `test123` user.
- Then putting AND condition to make sure all items are coming from starting of this current year.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks! I've tested it in my environment this is working fine.